# googleapi service account create workspace user events

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

Is it possible using a service account to add events in the user's calendar ?
For example given a internal email (in our workspace), could we add an event for this user ?

We have a configured service account with Domain-wide Delegation, we are able to list users, create new one etc. But we would like to access their calendar to add new events.

Is it possible to achieve ?

### Edit

We do not want our user to use a OAuth2 consent screen, we want to do it smoothly without them to need to interact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up [domain wide deligation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) for the service account to a user on your domain.

Then yes the service account will be able to act on behalf of that user and add an event in their calendar.

Service accounts have their consent preconfigured so no consent screen will be shown.